# How can I Connect flutter app to aws iot?

Tags: flutter, aws-iot, mongoose-os

I want to control aws iot devices through flutter mobile app. I registered device in aws iot things, Now how can I control that device through my mobile app.
I'm using Nodemcu with mongoose os.

Comment: I have the same issue, and have been working to get it working by combining multiple libraries and AwsSigV4, I will let you know if I get it working. Please let me know if you already got it working?